# Determine distance between two devices

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I have a question about Core bluetooth in swift language,
Is this framework can determine the distance by meter between two devices ? 
And it have working on background?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not normally, but features like this are being added as part of the new contact tracing API

https://www.apple.com/covid19/contacttracing

Before that, device to device Bluetooth could not be in the background.

Note: you will not be able to use this API unless you have a legitimate health app backed by a government or established health organization.